# Add property to User Control and make them visible in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

as in the subject, I have created a user control added to the toolbox as a component. After dragging on the test form it looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAW9i.jpg)

My goal is to add several properties that will be visible after dragging to the form so that the user can freely change according to his preferences, e.g. value, text, scale on the trackbar etc.
At the moment I have a few settings set up rigidly, but I am interested in actively changing the property to any value. Component code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SuwakKomponent
{
    public partial class Suwak : UserControl
    {
        public Suwak()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void trackBar3_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            trackBar3.Minimum = 10;
            trackBar3.Maximum = 1000;
            label4.Text = trackBar3.Value.ToString();

            int value;
            if (Int32.TryParse(label4.Text, out value))
            {

                if (value < 100)
                {
                    label4.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    label4.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else if (value >= 100 && value <= 499)
                {
                    label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    label4.BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else if (value >= 500 && value <= 799)
                {
                    label4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    label4.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else if (value >= 800)
                {
                    label4.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    label4.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you'e asking here.

Comment: if your control should look like input from user, take input from user and pass them into user control (usually through constructor) and change user control accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean that the properties should be `visible` to the developer in the properties window? if so you just need to add public properties to your control class and they should come up in the properties window in the designer

Comment: You need to create some public properties. [Walkthrough: Authoring a Composite Control with Visual C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-authoring-a-composite-control-with-visual-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to write public properties.
Here is an example for a property that shows up in the `properties window` and that will allow setting the `Minimum` property of the `trackBar3`

```
public partial class Suwak : UserControl
{
    public Suwak()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int TrackBarMinium
    {
        get { return trackBar3.Minimum; }
        set { trackBar3.Minimum = value; }
    }

    ...
```

In the code from the `set` you can write more lines of code if needed.
More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-authoring-a-composite-control-with-visual-csharp)